# Switch case pass multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have four dynamically inputs. User select how many wants. 
In input he enter article ID and on success I send this in URL.
Url can have only two or three or four id

```
'http://someurl/' + ID + '/someParams'
example: 'http://someurl/991,992,993,994/someParams'
```

I pass ID's from html to controller

```
$scope.submitChoice = function (name) {
    $scope.choices.forEach(function(choice, index){
        if(choice.name)
        {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    var firstId = choice.name;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    var secondId = choice.name;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    var thirdId = choice.name;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    var fourthId = choice.name;
                    break;
            }
            console.log(firstId, secondId, thirdId, fourthId);
            $scope.getBenchIdForCompare(firstId, secondId, thirdId,fourthId);
        }
    })
}
```

I use `SWITCH CASE` and `INDEX` because I need every of this ID set to unique var (because of another part of my app). 
Problem is, when I submit entered ID in input, I get this in my console when I 
    `console.log(firstId, secondId, thirdId, fourthId);`

console

```
991 undefined undefined undefined
undefined 992 undefined undefined
undefined undefined 993 undefined
undefined undefined undefined 994
```

And I can not pass this to another function because I need to have `991 992 993 994`

Is there another way to make this?

Comment: Declare variables outside of `for` loop as well as move `console.log` and function `$scope.getBenchIdForCompare` call outside `for` loop.

Comment: @Arter, instead of variables take `$scope.variable_names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` instead and create an `array`. Once `array` is created, you can join them using `join()` method and you will get readymade comma separated string. This comma separated string can be added to get desired URL.

```js
$scope.submitChoice = function(name) {
  var choices = $scope.choices.map(function(choice){
    return choice.name;
  });
  console.log(choices.join(','));
  $scope.getBenchIdForCompare(choices[0], choices[1], choices[2], choices[3]);
}
```

ES6 version (using the spread operator):

```
$scope.submitChoice = function(name) {
  let choices = $scope.choices.map(choice => choice.name)
  console.log(choices.join(','));
  $scope.getBenchIdForCompare(...choices);
}
```

Comment: I think you can even print it as a table with: `console.table(choices)`

Comment: Nice for ES6 

Comment: That's exactly what I need... Thank you, i learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you're calling the function on every single element of the choices array. Every element has a unique index. This causes the switch statement's case to be true only once for each element. But, since you're looping through the choices array, the other three variables never get assigned any value. Hence the `undefined`s.
I would suggest to move the declarations of the variables and their usage out of the forEach loop. Just use the forEach for assigning the values and then the code should  work fine